# Importing csv file into hive yielding more records

Tags: csv, hive

Importing **csv file** into table yielding more records with null values.

```
create table result(SecondaryRatings String, CommentIds String, LastModeratedTime String)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

After importing 10 records into result table, getting 12 records in the table. Getting 10 records plus 2 additional records with null values.

Comment: does the csv file have empty rows i.e. newline characters at the end of the 10th row, i mean the enter key

Comment: @nidhin It is containing only 10 records, no enter key.

Comment: can you check the data in hdfs. Does it contain 12 rows?

Comment: Yes it consists of 10. If I add more records say 50 it is populating upto 60 records in hive table, for 100 records it is populating 123 records.